# retain material badge value after page refresh angular 9

Tags: typescript, angular-material, material-design

I use material badge notification show to display new notifiactions to the user.
This is what I have tried so far:

```
badgeCounter: number;
hideMatBadge: boolean = true;

ngOnInit() {
this.loadData();
this.hideMatBadge = false;


localStorage.setItem("badgeCounter", badgeCounter.toString());
localStorage.getItem("badgeCounter"); 

 }

 incrementCount() {
 this.badgeCounter++;
 this.hideMatBadge = false;

  }

  decreaseCount() {
   if (this.badgeCounter < 0)
    return;
   this.badgeCounter--;
  if (this.badgeCounter == 0) {
    this.hideMatBadge = true;
  }
 }
```

But it doesnt work. Actually this `badgeCounter: number;` it mess my page I have to use it like that `badgeCounter: number = 0;` but then on refresh it retruns to zero again.
Any idea
Thank you

Comment: You need to assign the value you get from localStorage. `this.badgeCounter = localStorage.getItem("badgeCounter");`

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Eldar, you need to assign the value you get from localStorage. And retrieve it too so your final code should look something like:

```
incrementCount() {
 this.badgeCounter++;
 localStorage.setItem("badgeCounter", this.badgeCounter.toString());
 this.hideMatBadge = false;
}

decreaseCount() {
  this.badgeCounter = localStorage.getItem("badgeCounter");
  if (this.badgeCounter < 0)
    return;
   this.badgeCounter--;
  if (this.badgeCounter == 0) {
    this.hideMatBadge = true;
}
```

Comment: thank you for reply. Actually the incrementCount() and decreaseCount() work ok. My problem is on page refresh...it returns the value of notification to zero.

Comment: Hum.. ok. When you inspect your localStorage (using the console) value after an incrementCount() has been called, is the value properly set?

Comment: @touinta you should remove this line `localStorage.setItem("badgeCounter", badgeCounter.toString());` from `ngOnInit`

Comment: @touinta ok is there anywhere else in your component where you change the value of your badgeCounter? If no, I think it would be best if you could provide a StackBlitz demo so that we can investigate further.

Comment: @Terry and @Eldar. Thank you for your help. I finally used  `localStorage.setItem('badgeCounter', JSON.stringify(this.badgeCounter));`  in `incrementCount()` and `this.badgeCounter = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('badgeCounter'));` in `ngOnInit()` and it worked.